# updating a foreignkey field in other model for all m2m entries when saving

Tags: python, django

One model (periodiccertification) is linked by a foreignkey to another model (assets). This periodic model is also linked by a foreignkey (blank and null true) to access the m2m relation (assets) of another model (projectconditions).

the relevant fields of periodiccertification in db:

[pc db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TXfr.png)

the m2m relation of projectconditions:

[m2m pcond](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0g0J2.png)

The question is:

When saving projectconditions all the assets in the periodiccertification model need to be updated by only one field : projectconditions_id (the foreignkey). This way it is possible to filter all assets that are related to the projectconditions batch.

Can this be done by overriding save_model() or does it require a different signal? So what I'm trying to accomplish every time a projectconditions form is submitted:

**for each** .projectconditions.assets.asset_id **that is equal to** periodiccertification.asset_id:

**update** processes.periodiccertification.projectconditions_id **with** projects.projectsconditions_id

Does anyone know a pythonic way to do this while saving (perhaps problems that the assets you're about to save are not there yet?) or during some kind of post_save function?

trying to learn python (beginner level), but hopefully the attempt below furtherly demonstrates what is meant:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
"""obtain all entries in Periodic Certification Model that has the same asset_id as in m2m"""
certification_asset = PeriodicCertification.objects.get(asset_id=assets.asset_id)
""""save the current projectconditions"""
for asset_id in certification_assets:
        certification_asset.projectconditions_id = obj.id
    obj.save()
```

Comment: Can you post your models here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably use Django's [update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update) function to make the change you want.

So in your `ProjectConditions` model:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ProjectConditions, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    PeriodicCertification.objects.filter(asset_id__in=[x.id for x in self.assets]).update(projectconditions_id=self.id)
```

The `[x.id for x in self.assets.all()]` should give you a list of all `asset_id`s in the current instance's assets ManyToMany relation with assets.  You then filter your `PeriodicCertification` model for only instances with an `asset_id` that matches those in the list.  Finally, you use `update` to set the `projectconditions_id` field to the id of the current instance.

I tried to get the details right, but if not hopefully it points you in the right direction.